# Conda: installing local development package into single conda environment

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

If I were using a virtualenv, I would activate my project's virtual environment then install the package I am developing in develop mode.  Something like the following:

```
workon superbad
pip install -e fnawesome
```

This allows my package `fnawesome` to be accessible with any code updates in my `superbad` virtual environment.  If I switch to any other environment, including the default environment, `superbad` id not accessible.

How are people doing similar setups using conda?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can configure a list of default packages that will be installed into any conda environment automatically

```
conda config --add create_default_packages pip --add create_default_packages ipython
```

will make it so that `conda create` will always include `pip` and `ipython` in new environments (this command is the same as adding

```
create_default_packages:
  - ipython
  - pip
```

to your `.condarc` file).

To create an environment without these, use `conda create --no-default-packages`.

Comment: Thanks this is a great improvement

Answer (score 11):

Okay, I figured out the issue behind the question.

If you create a conda environment, make sure to include pip and ipython.  Otherwise, it will not setup the path to point to environment specific versions of these utilities.

so:

```
conda create -n superbad scikit-learn
source activate superbad
pip install -e fnawesome  # (installs in default env b/c pip is global pip)
ipython  # runs global ipython with access to global site packages
python # runs the environment's python with no access to fnawesome
```

this works as expected:

```
conda create -n superbad scikit-learn pip ipython
source activate superbad
pip install -e fnawesome  # installing into superbad site packages
ipython  # runs superbad ipython
python  # runs the environment's python with access to fnawesome
source deactivate
ipython # no access to fnawesome
```

Comment: Nice! I think you're missing actually installing ipython and pip when creating the second environment, right?

Comment: yup, added.  The default "anaconda" package can also be used.  As it wraps "pip", "ipython", and a bunch of other libraries you probably want if you are using anaconda python. It is far from minimal.

Answer (score 0):

try this, specify the virtual environment when installing a python package:

```
conda install -n superbad fnawesome
```

Answer (score 0):

Activate the environment int which the package is to be installed

```
conda activate [environment]
```

Install the package

```
conda install [package]
```