# Use package from Github in Conda Virtual Environment

Tags: python, git, jupyter, conda

**Setup**

- Conda virtual environment
- Coding in a Jupyter notebook
- Python version 3.6

I have Googled, searched through the Conda help, github help on this site as wel as found closely relevant questions, that just don't answer mine:

- [Conda install package from github including requirements.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44594994/conda-install-package-from-github-including-requirements-txt)
- [Conda: installing local development package into single conda environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928566/conda-installing-local-development-package-into-single-conda-environment)

That first one comes close though.

Basically my question comes down to:

For my code to work i need to import this repo: https://github.com/nicocanali/airtable-python

How can I get this to be used in my Jupyter Notebook?

I'll need to add it to my virtual environment. But how?

Comment: You just activate your environment (so that the correct pip is called) and use pip install in some compatible form for installing directly from github (see all the other questions about that).

Comment: to download it into your home directory and you can open it in Jupyter Notebook: git clone https://github.com/pcorpet/airtable.py.git

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

1. Install git in the virtual environment: (conda install git)
2. Clone the project. (git clone [URL])
3. Install the package (cd to package directory that contains setup.py.
4. Then run "python setup.py install").

Found the answer in the first part in this video: [How to Install Python Package from GitHub](https://youtube.com/watch?v=5hq0Edi2Ou8)

Answer (score 1):

To install https://github.com/nicocanali/airtable-python to your jupyter.

Download the .zip of the repo from the github website.

To install it in jupyter enter the following command from the anaconda console.

```
pip install [path_to_.zip_file_on_pc]
```

Works on any github file

Answer (score 1):

Found a simple solution here:

https://medium.com/i-want-to-be-the-very-best/installing-packages-from-github-with-conda-commands-ebf10de396f4

For example, to install the package located at
https://github.com/Netflix/metaflow, navigate to your desired environment in the Anaconda prompt, activate the environment, and then execute the following commands:

```
conda install git
conda install pip
pip install git+git://github.com/Netflix/metaflow.git
```

(Note that the git package is available in Anaconda Navigator, so can be installed from there instead of from the Anaconda prompt.)