# No such file or directory error when installing github package in anaconda

Tags: python, github, pip, anaconda

I am trying to install this module from github.

https://github.com/ChristianSchneeweiss/Chat-txt-to-csv

First, I am following the steps listed here.
https://medium.com/i-want-to-be-the-very-best/installing-packages-from-github-with-conda-commands-ebf10de396f4

so I used this line in Anaconda Powershell Prompt

`pip install git+git://github.com/ChristianSchneeweiss/Chat-txt-to-csv.git`

it didn't work. and then I used this code, based on the suggestions here.
[Use package from Github in Conda Virtual Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46076754/use-package-from-github-in-conda-virtual-environment)

`pip install C:\Users\Lulz\Documents\mamanitip\chat_wa\Chat-txt-to-csv-master.zip`

it didn't work either. both codes resulted in this error.

```
     command: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Lulz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-2cr6dd41\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Lulz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-2cr6dd41\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Lulz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-3o0zsjkm'
         cwd: C:\Users\Lulz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-2cr6dd41\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tokenize.py", line 447, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Lulz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-2cr6dd41\\setup.py'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

i've tried creating new Microsoft accounts, and installing in a new environment, but it still didn't work. it always resulted in the same error, just different users (as I change Microsoft accounts). what did I do wrong? thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package at https://github.com/ChristianSchneeweiss/Chat-txt-to-csv cannot be installed with `pip` because it does not have the file `setup.py`. What you can do instead is to download the project onto your computer, install the project's dependencies, and then use the project from its directory. If you run python from within that project's directory, it will find the package.

```
git clone https://github.com/ChristianSchneeweiss/Chat-txt-to-csv
cd Chat-txt-to-csv
python -m pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
python convert.py chat.txt
```

Comment: thank you for the help! it did start converting the txt files, although my message still didn't get converted. I suppose it's something with the package. thanks!