# How to safely add GitHub packages to a Conda environment for export

Tags: python, github, anaconda, conda

I have installed a package from GitHub in a Conda environment and subsequently exported it. When I came to install the environment on another machine, I found that the GitHub package had been listed under the pip dependencies, causing the installation to fail when it found no such package on the PyPI server. I removed that dependency manually but then had to painstakingly remove a series of other dependencies that had been created, all with incompatible versions.

So... my question is, when I need to use a package from GitHub in a Conda virtual environment, how can I save the dependency? This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32799944/4776977) suggests that you can list GitHub dependencies in the pip section of the environment YAML, but that is not what gets created when I export the environment according to [Conda's documentation](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#exporting-the-environment-file).

I can think of 2 workarounds, but neither is ideal:

1. Manually edit the YAML, removing any new pip dependencies following the install and replacing them with the GitHub installation of the main package.
2. Export the environment *before* installing any packages from GitHub, and keep a separate note that these need to be installed manually after installing the environment.

Sorry if this has been answered elsewhere, but I can't find it. I see other people have given advice on [how to install GitHub packages in a Conda environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46076754/use-package-from-github-in-conda-virtual-environment) but no one seems to have broached the issue of how you then replicate that environment successfully.

Comment: How did you install the package from GitHub into the environment?

Comment: Define a YAML *from the start* and include the GitHub package in there under the `pip:` section. Automated environment exporting is simply never as good as deliberate engineering.